# it doesn't recognize "sum". why?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

It doesn't recognize "sum". why?

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
FROM clients c, contracts_rent r, payments p
WHERE c.c_id = r.c_id
AND r.contract_id = p.contract_id and sum>1300
GROUP BY c.c_id
```

Comment: what was error message? Is it MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
FROM clients c, contracts_rent r, payments p
WHERE c.c_id = r.c_id
AND r.contract_id = p.contract_id
GROUP BY c.c_id 
HAVING SUM( p.p_sum ) > 1300
```

When you want to filter on the aggregate function value, you use the HAVING keyword

Answer (score 2):

Aggregated columns can't usually be handled within a `where` clause since that clause happens *before* aggregation.

What you need is the `having` clause, which occurs *after* aggregation.

Compare something like:

```
select id, something, p_sum from tbl
where p_sum > 100
```

into:

```
select id, something, sum(p_sum) from tbl
group by something
having sum(p_sum) > 100
```

The former selects individual rows where the sum in that row is greater than 100. The latter groups on `something` then selects the grouped rows that have an aggregate summ greater than 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_name, SUM( p.p_sum ) AS sum
FROM clients c, contracts_rent r, payments p
WHERE c.c_id = r.c_id
AND r.contract_id = p.contract_id 
GROUP BY c.c_id 
HAVING SUM(p.p_sum) > 1300
```

Make sure that you keep Joins in mind to get appropriate result.